# perl regex matching challenge finding size of folder and sub-folders on Windows

Tags: regex, perl, directory, size

I'm very new to programming but have written a script that uses use `File::Find` to calculate the size of a folder and sub-folders using the following line from an example:

```perl
find(sub { $total += -s if -f }, "$scanlocation.vir");
```

This works most of the time, however, there was one folder that was very deep and it displayed the error: `Can't cd to ../../../../../../..` and stopped.

I've tried referencing the scan location by local drive letter, network assigned letter from another computer and even a UNC \server\share format.   Referring to the local drive letter, displays the error and the other two methods do not error but also do not calculate the total.

I have a directory listing that ends like this:

```
 Directory of x:\ready\14235.20013336.vir\2020-01-13\HP27680588713\PUBLIC\archive\Rasphone

    03/07/2020  05:24 PM    <DIR>          .
    03/07/2020  05:24 PM    <DIR>          ..
    06/24/2013  05:22 PM                 2 rasphone.pbk
                   1 File(s)              2 bytes

     Directory of x:\ready\14235.20013336.vir\2020-01-13\HP27680588713\PUBLIC\archive\WirelessKeyView

    03/07/2020  05:24 PM    <DIR>          .
    03/07/2020  05:24 PM    <DIR>          ..
    01/13/2020  06:39 PM                 0 WirelessKeyView.txt
    01/13/2020  06:39 PM                 0 WirelessKeyViewExport.txt
                   2 File(s)              0 bytes

         Total Files **Listed:
                8693 File(s)  8,711,887,757 bytes**
                5852 Dir(s)  98,156,724,404,224 bytes free
```

And thought a regex could pull out the value.   I've gotten close with `/Listed:.*File\(s\).*?bytes/gs` but I can only match down to the bolded part above.

My ultimate goal is to get the size on disk of a specified folder including sub-folders in bytes.   I'm already creating the txt file with the direct output.

So, any suggestions or point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does it help if you use `find`'s `no_chdir` option?

Comment: Does it help if you prepend the path with `//?/x:/ready/...` instead of `x:/ready/...`

Answer (score 1):

```
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my ($total) = $data =~ /Total[ ]Files[ ]Listed: \s+ \d+ \s+ File\(s\) \s+ ([\d,]+) \s+ bytes/x
   or die("No match");

print("Total: $total\n");

__DATA__
03/07/2020  05:24 PM    <DIR>          .
03/07/2020  05:24 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/24/2013  05:22 PM                 2 rasphone.pbk
               1 File(s)              2 bytes

 Directory of x:\ready\14235.20013336.vir\2020-01-13\HP27680588713\PUBLIC\archive\WirelessKeyView

03/07/2020  05:24 PM    <DIR>          .
03/07/2020  05:24 PM    <DIR>          ..
01/13/2020  06:39 PM                 0 WirelessKeyView.txt
01/13/2020  06:39 PM                 0 WirelessKeyViewExport.txt
               2 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
            8693 File(s)  8,711,887,757 bytes
            5852 Dir(s)  98,156,724,404,224 bytes free
```

Comment: I used this regex in an online regex builder that matches it against the file and I think this is exactly what I need.    But when I put it into code and open the file, $total isn't assigned anything.

Comment: open FOO,"X:\\ready\\14235.20013336.virddd\\14235.20013336.dir";
$data = join('',<FOO>);
close FOO;
 
# print "DATA $data\n";
 
my ($total) = $data =~ "/Total[ ]Files[ ]Listed: \s+ \d+ \s+ File\(s\) \s+ ([\d,]+)/x";
print "\nTOTAL $total\n";

Comment: Tip: Don't use global vars! Use 3-arg open, and check if `open` succeeds. Use `open(my $foo, "<", $qfn) or die("Can't open \"$qfn\": $!\n");`

Comment: The last could be relevant. If `open` failed, then `$data` will be an empty string.

Comment: There was a `\s+` missing before `bytes`. Fixed.

Comment: That did it!    Thank you thank you.    I'm going to study your regex and hopefully, I'll get better because of it.